# Broadcast receiver return android AppWidget layout to initial size, not to the resized size

Tags: android, android-appwidget, android-broadcastreceiver

I am developing AppWidget which:

1. Can be resized and handle:

> `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged`

2. Should be updated on interval chosen by user and handle:

> `onReceive`

I have three layouts for my widget for different widget sizes.
The problem is that when I resize the widget and onReceive is called, widget always gets initial view. For example, widget initial layout is 4x1 and onReceive from BroadCastReceiver is being called everything is OK. When I resize my widget to size 4x2 after onReceive is being called, the widget is with size 4x1 again. 
Does anybody has idea why?

Here are some snippets from my code:

1. I have three widget layouts: widget_layout.xml, widget_layout_1.xml, widget_layout_2.xml
2. Here is the configuration about my widget:

   `<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
   android:minHeight="40dip"
   android:minWidth="390dip"
   android:resizeMode="vertical"
   android:configure="com.test.ConfigurationDummy"
   >
   </appwidget-provider>`
3. Here is the code for my widget provider:

> ```
>  public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
>  private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
>  int [] appWidgetIds;
> ```

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "onUpdate():update widget instance ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.appWidgetManager=appWidgetManager;
    this.appWidgetIds= Arrays.copyOf(appWidgetIds,appWidgetIds.length);
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_layout);
    // do some with the view 
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "TimeWidgetRemoved id(s):" + appWidgetIds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled (Context context){
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDisabled():last widget instance removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

/**
 * this is called when first widget is created
 *
 * @param context
 */
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "onEnabled id(s):" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onEnabled(context);

    //TODO this should be read from StoreUtils class
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("AsebaSave", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putLong("refreshTime", 500).apply();
    //TODO cards should be read from StoreUtils class

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, prefs.getLong("refreshTime", 500), prefs.getLong("refreshTime", 500), pi);
}

@TargetApi(16)
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    Toast.makeText(context, " onAppWidgetOptionsChanged" + appWidgetId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);
    int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, getRemoteViews(appWidgetManager,context, minWidth, minHeight, appWidgetId));
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
}

private RemoteViews getRemoteViews(AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,Context context, int minWidth, int minHeight, int appWidgetId) {
    int rows = getCellsForSize(minHeight);
    RemoteViews updateViews;
    switch (rows) {
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(context, "case 1: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout_1);
            Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            return updateViews;
        case 2:
             updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout_2);
            Toast.makeText(context, "case 2: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent svcIntent1 = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            svcIntent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            return updateViews;
        default:
            updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            Toast.makeText(context, "case 3: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent svcIntent2 = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            svcIntent2.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            return updateViews;
    }
}


private static int getCellsForSize(int size) {
    int n = 2;
    while (70 * n - 30 < size) {
        ++n;
    }
    return n - 1;
}

public Card getCard(Context context, String key){
    SharedPreferences settings;
    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(ConfigurationDummy.preferencesFile,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settings.contains(key)) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = settings.getString(key, "");
        Card obj = gson.fromJson(json, Card.class);
        return obj;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

}`

Here is the code for my BroadCastReceiver:

> ```
>   public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>     Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive():update widget instance ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "UPDATE_DONUT");
>     //Acquire the lock
>     wl.acquire();
>     //You can do the processing here update the widget/remote views.
>     AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
>     int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
>     Intent intent1=new Intent(context,WidgetProvider.class);
>     Bundle extras = intent1.getExtras();
>     if (extras != null) {
>         Toast.makeText(context, "if (extras != null) { ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
>                 AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
>         Toast.makeText(context, "Widget ID "+mAppWidgetId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
>     Bundle options=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(mAppWidgetId);
>     int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);
>     int rows=getCellsForSize(minWidth);
>     RemoteViews remoteViews;
>     switch (rows) {
>         case 1:
>             Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive():remoteView 1 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout_1);
>             break;
>         case 2:
>             Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive():remoteView 2 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout_2);
>             break;
>         case 3:
>             Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive():remoteView 3 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             remoteViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
>             break;
>         default:
>             Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive():remoteView default ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             remoteViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
>     }
>     new AsyncTaskRandom(remoteViews,context,rows).execute();
>     //Release the lock
>     wl.release();
> }
> //TODO This AsyncTask should call account balance
> private class AsyncTaskRandom extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void > {
>     private RemoteViews remoteViews;
>     private int rows;
>     private Context context;
>     int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
>     public AsyncTaskRandom(RemoteViews remoteViews,Context context,int rows){
>         this.remoteViews=remoteViews;
>         this.context=context;
>         this.rows=rows;
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
>         try {
>             Thread.currentThread();
>             Thread.sleep(5000);
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
>         super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
>         Random rand = new Random();
>         switch (rows) {
>             case 1:
>             // do something with layout
>             case 2:
>             // do something with layout
>             case 3:
>             // do something with layout
>             default:
>             // do something with layout
>         }
>         ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
>         AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
>         manager.updateAppWidget(thiswidget, remoteViews);
>     }
> }
> private static int getCellsForSize(int size) {
>     int n = 2;
>     while (70 * n - 30 < size) {
>         ++n;
>     }
>     return n - 1;
> }
> public Card getCard(Context context, String key){
>     SharedPreferences settings;
>     settings = context.getSharedPreferences(ConfigurationDummy.preferencesFile,
>             Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>     if (settings.contains(key)) {
>         Gson gson = new Gson();
>         String json = settings.getString(key, "");
>         Card obj = gson.fromJson(json, Card.class);
>         return obj;
>     } else
>         return null;
> }
> ```
>
> }

When I tried this:

> ```
>   Intent intent1=new Intent(context,WidgetProvider.class);
>     Bundle extras = intent1.getExtras();
>     if (extras != null) {
>         Toast.makeText(context, "if (extras != null) { ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
>                 AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
>         Toast.makeText(context, "Widget ID "+mAppWidgetId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> ```

mAppWidgetId is 0. 
And in this piece of code

> Bundle options=appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(mAppWidgetId);
>     int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

options is null and minWidth =0.

I don't have idea why?